# Logic Apps - Http+Swagger - Header attribute for token based authentication

Tags: json, azure, http, swagger, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to add headers to a Http+Swagger  action in Logic App.

When I add a simple Http Action, I can clearly see the Headers in the designer.
However, with Swagger+Http action it disappears.

I am using token based authentication and need to add Header to this API call.
Hence, I modified the code view like below but it does not seem to help!

Cannot find much resources with regards to this. Any help is appreciated.

Thank You.

```
"Information_Process": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "body": {
                                    "fileId": "Test.json",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "item": {
                                                "prop1": "@items('For_each')?['Item']?['prop1']",
                                                "prop2": "@items('For_each')?['Item']?['prop2']",
                                                "prop3": "@items('For_each')?['Item']?['prop3']"                                               
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]

                                },
                                "headers": {
                                    "Authorization": "@{concat('Bearer ',variables('BearerTokenValue'))}"
                                },
                                "method": "post",
                                "uri": "https://appone.azurewebsites.net/api/information/proccessing"
                            },
                            "metadata": {
                                "apiDefinitionUrl": "https://appone.azurewebsites.net//swagger/docs/v1",
                                "swaggerSource": "custom"
                            },                           
                            "type": "Http"
                        }
```

Comment: Please share the swagger document you are using. The url mentioned in json isn't there, or probably you didn't put in the correct url intentionally. https://appone.azurewebsites.net//swagger/docs/v1

Comment: what is the error you re getting ? Can you share your swagger definition ? it possible you need to add the authorization header in the definition itself

Answer (score 2):

The official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app#using-parameters-and-secure-parameters) states to make use of the parameters to send and receive a token.

```
"parameters": {
               "secret": {
                  "type": "SecureString"
               }
            }
```

Or you can try like this

```
"HTTP": {
    "inputs": {
        "headers': { 
        "Authorization": "@concat('Basic ', base64('username:password'))",
        "Content-Type ": "application/json"
    },
    "method ": "GET ",
    "uri": "someurl"
   },
   "runAfter": (),
   "type": "Http"
   }
```

[image]